# How to get a COUNT() value when GROUP BY has no row?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, aggregate-functions

`RDMS : MariaDB 10.1.23`

#### MCRE :

```
create table entity
(
    id_entity int auto_increment,
    created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint product_log_pk
        primary key (id_entity)
);

INSERT INTO entity SET created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
INSERT INTO entity SET created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
INSERT INTO entity SET created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

-- I would like this to return 0
SELECT IF(COUNT(e.id_entity) = 0, 0, e.id_entity) 
FROM entity e
WHERE e.created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY e.created_at;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32a01/1

---

Consider the following query :

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(e.some_field) = 0, 0, e.some_field) 
FROM entity e
WHERE e.created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY e.created_at
```

Without the GROUP BY clause, I know that `COUNT()` will return `0` if no row match the query.

I also know that, if my GROUP BY "fails" (If i have no row to group by, in my example, if no row satisfy `e.created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY`) then, COUNT() will not return anything (0 row). How can I make sure COUNT() returns 0 (1 row with the value `0`) in that case ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping is done after where clause is evaluated; if the where clause eliminates all rows then there is nothing to group.

I am guessing that you want conditional aggregation. Here is an example:

```
name | dept | gender
-----+------+-------
jane | acc  | f
john | acc  | m
jack | hr   | m
jake | hr   | m
```

And query to count all female employees by department:

```sql
SELECT dept, COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 END)
FROM employee
-- WHERE gender = ... will/could eliminate entire group(s)
GROUP BY dept
```

```
dept | count
-----+------
acc  | 1
hr   | 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You only seem to care about one row.  For this, just remove the `GROUP BY`.

I have no idea what the `IF()` is supposed to be doing

```
SELECT COUNT(e.some_field)
FROM entity e
WHERE e.created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

If you want to return the values i `some_field`, then `GROUP_CONCAT()` will put them all in one column:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(e.some_field)
FROM entity e
WHERE e.created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

Both of these *always* return one row, because they are aggregation queries with no `GROUP BY`.  The first returns `0` and the second `NULL` if no rows match.

Comment: My question was not really about "Removing the GROUP BY clause to always get a row" - Let's say I need to `GROUP BY`, (for some reason). How can I manage the case where my `GROUP BY` has no row, and I still want to SELECT something (let's say `0`) ?

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" way is

```
 COALESCE(value, 0)
```

It is usually used this way:

```
COALESCE( ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ), 0)
```